# How to store generated strings in a vector in C++?

Tags: c++, string, vector

I am still moving from Java to C++ and I am struggling with strings.  I need to generate some strings and store them somewhere so that they are available to my program after the object that created them is destroyed.  I tried storing them in a vector of strings but I get a **Segmentation Fault - double free**.  A basic version of what I am doing, and that reproduces the problem is here:

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

std::string makeString(){
    std::stringstream s;
    s << "Test string";
    return s.str();
}

int main(){
    std::vector<std::string> storage;
    storage.reserve(1);
    storage[0] = makeString();
    return 0;
}
```

The debugger marks the error in the line:

```
storage[0] = makeString();
```

I will thank a lot and insight on what is going on here and how to avoid it, please.

Comment: A quick fix is to use `resize` instead of `reserve`. Trying to emulate a Java StringBuilder is not the greatest idea either. They are different languages.

Comment: I got no error when i compile this!.Can u post the error also?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`vector.reserve` does not change the size of the vector. You will have to use `resize` instead of `reserve`. Another option is to use `push_back()`:

```
 storage.push_back(makeString());
```

Comment: You can use `reserve` in conjunction with `push_back` (or the insert iterators, etc) if you wish to avoid reallocation during insertion.

Comment: Thanks! resize solved my problem.  (I really need to use assignment instead of push_back).